# Change radio button status when i click on any place of div

Tags: jquery

```
             EventPrices += "<div class='after-price' id=divPrice>";
                       if (localStorage.getItem('SelectedRoleName') != null)
                       {
                           if (localStorage.getItem('SelectedRoleName').toString().trim() == "Admin") {
                               EventPrices += "<span class='price'><input type='radio' value='" + Item.PriceId + "' id='chkEventPrices'  class='fa fa-check' name='chkEventPrices' title='" + Item.Price + "' onclick='CalculateTotal();'><label> $" + Item.Price + " </label> </span> ";
                           }
                           else {
                               EventPrices += "<span class='price'><input type='radio' value='" + Item.PriceId + "' id='chkEventPrices' disabled= 'disabled'  class='fa fa-check' name='chkEventPrices' title='" + Item.Price + "' onclick='CalculateTotal();'><label> $" + Item.Price + " </label> </span> ";
                           }
                       } else {
                           EventPrices += "<span class='price'><input type='radio' value='" + Item.PriceId + "' id='chkEventPrices' disabled= 'disabled'  class='fa fa-check' name='chkEventPrices' title='" + Item.Price + "' onclick='CalculateTotal();'><label> $" + Item.Price + " </label> </span> ";
                       }


                       EventPrices += "<span class='date'>After " + moment(Item.EarlyBirdDate).format("MMM DD, YYYY") + " </span>";
                       EventPrices += "</div></div>";
                       EventPrices += "<div><span id='spnEventPriceLiteralDetails_" + i + "'>" + EventPriceLiteraldetals + "</span></div>";


                    }


                    EventPrices += "</div><br/>";
                    i++;
                });
```

This is my code.now if i click on particular radio button it is taking..i want if i click on box only radio button will select.

Comment: Can you post full code and rephrase your words ? quite confusing now.

Comment: you can use label for this purpose , please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527721/using-label-for-on-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
  $("#isClicked").text("selected radio value is " + ($('input[type=radio]:checked').val() == "1" ? "Male" : "Female"));
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="r1"> Male
  <input type="radio" class="hidden" name="group1" id="r1" value="1" />
</label>
<label for="r2"> FeMale
  <input type="radio" class="hidden" name="group1" id="r2" value="2" />
</label>
<br />
<div id="isClicked"></div>
```

Please check this. Here whenever user clicks a label, its corresponding radio button click event gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As per you **`Q`** am guessing your function is working on click on radio button.

So let's take that you `radio` button class is `.radio` and 'div' class is `.test` in this case if you want we can go with `.trigger' of jQuery.
eg:

```
$('body').on('click',`.test`,function(){
  $('.radio').trigger('click');
});
```

This will work as per me.ty

Comment: missing ' after body