# Update label radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I update the label for a radio input element in JavaScript (or jQuery)?
For example, change the text from 'Swift' to 'Python'

```html
<label for="language">
  <input type="radio" id="language" name="language" value="main">Swift
</label>
```

Comment: What JS have you tried that failed?

Comment: Check you HTML syntax also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527721/using-label-for-on-radio-buttons

Comment: The first one:(<label for="button one"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1" value="1" /> button one</label>) is the one I have not idea how to do because the text I want to update, is after the input tag. So I just could not grab the label and update its text

Comment: `$('label[for=language]').html('Python'); ` changes the text but deletes the radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-arrange the HTML, you can target the label and change the text.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="language" name="language" value="main">
<label for="language">Swift</label>
```

JQuery JS

```
$('label[for="language"]').text('Python');
```

Standard JS

```
var find = document.querySelectorAll('label[for="language"]');
if (find.length>0) {
    find[0].innerText = 'Python';
}
```

If you cannot or do not want to re-arrange the HTML, maybe wrap the text with a `<span>` element and target that.

HTML with Span

```
<label for="language">
    <input type="radio" id="language" name="language" value="main"><span>Swift</span>
</label>
```

JQuery JS for HTML with Span

```
$('label[for="language"] span').text('Python');
```

Standard JS for HTML with Span

```
var find = document.querySelectorAll('label[for="language"] span');
if (find.length>0) {
    find[0].innerText = 'Python';
}
```

If you cannot edit the HTML at all, then you may want to copy the radio button so it can be placed back into the element once you decide what text to display next to it.

HTML

```
<label for="language">
   <input type="radio" id="language" name="language" value="main">Swift
</label>
```

JQuery JS

```
var find = $('label[for="language"]');
var html = find.html();
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var radioButton = html.match(regex)[0];
find.html(radioButton + 'Python');
```

Standard JS

```
var find = document.querySelectorAll('label[for="language"]');
var html = find[0].innerHTML;
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var radioButton = html.match(regex)[0];
find[0].innerHTML = radioButton + 'Python';
```

Comment: The problem is that the html is written as such I cannot modified. Your code works fine with the span, it does change the text and keep the radio button which is fine. But without the span, it changes the text but deletes the radio button

Comment: @blueDroid I have updated the answer so that if you cannot change the HTML at all, you can still get the text to change. This is one work-around.

Comment: Great answer!!! Really appreciated!!!